# Spark get collection sorted by value

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, word-count

I was trying this tutorial http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html
I first created a collection from a file

```
textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

Then I tried a command to cound the words:

```
wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

To print the collection:

```
 wordCounts.collect()
```

I found how to sort it by word using the command sortByKey. I was wondering how it could be possible to do the same thing for sorting by the value, that in this case in the number that a word occur in the document.

Comment: Can you try something like this : `textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey()` ?

Comment: @user3702916 - eliasah's solution is for the Scala API. Convert it into Python and that should work. So instead of `map(item => item.swap)` try `map(lambda (x,y): (y,x))`.

Comment: How can we do this in Java API?

Comment: `...reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b).map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0])).sortByKey() ` or `sortByKey(0)` for descending order in python

Answer (score 32):

The sorting usually should be done before collect() is called since that returns the dataset to the driver program and also that is the way an hadoop map-reduce job would be programmed in java so that the final output you want is written (typically) to HDFS.  With the spark API this approach provides the flexibility of writing the output in "raw" form where you want, such as to a file where it could be used as input for further processing.

Using spark's scala API sorting before collect() can be done following eliasah's suggestion and using Tuple2.swap() twice, once before sorting and once after in order to produce a list of tuples sorted in increasing or decreasing order of their second field (which is named _2) and contains the count of number of words in their first field (named _1).  Below is an example of how this is scripted in spark-shell:

```
// this whole block can be pasted in spark-shell in :paste mode followed by <Ctrl>D
val file = sc.textFile("some_local_text_file_pathname")
val wordCounts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(word => (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _, 1)  // 2nd arg configures one task (same as number of partitions)
  .map(item => item.swap) // interchanges position of entries in each tuple
  .sortByKey(true, 1) // 1st arg configures ascending sort, 2nd arg configures one task
  .map(item => item.swap)
```

In order to reverse the ordering of the sort use sortByKey(false,1) since its first arg is the boolean value of ascending.  Its second argument is the number of tasks (equivilent to number of partitions) which is set to 1 for testing with a small input file where only one output data file is desired; reduceByKey also takes this optional argument.

After this the wordCounts RDD can be saved as text files to a directory with saveAsTextFile(directory_pathname) in which will be deposited one or more part-xxxxx files
(starting with part-00000) depending on the number of reducers configured for the job (1 output data file per reducer), a _SUCCESS file depending on if the job succeeded or not and .crc files.

Using pyspark a python script very similar to the scala script shown above produces output that is effectively the same. Here is the pyspark version demonstrating sorting a collection by value:

```
file = sc.textFile("file:some_local_text_file_pathname")
wordCounts = file.flatMap(lambda line: line.strip().split(" ")) \
    .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b, 1) \ # last arg configures one reducer task
    .map(lambda (a, b): (b, a)) \
    .sortByKey(1, 1) \ # 1st arg configures ascending sort, 2nd configures 1 task
    .map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))
```

In order to sortbyKey in descending order its first arg should be 0.  Since python captures leading and trailing whitespace as data, strip() is inserted before splitting each line on spaces, but this is not necessary using spark-shell/scala.

The main difference in the output of the spark and python version of wordCount is that where spark outputs (word,3) python outputs (u'word', 3).

For more information on spark RDD methods see http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html for python and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD for scala.

In the spark-shell, running collect() on wordCounts transforms it from an RDD to an Array[(String, Int)] = Array[Tuple2(String,Int)] which itself can be sorted on the second field of each Tuple2 element using:

```
Array.sortBy(_._2)
```

[sortBy](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Array@sortBy[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Repr) also takes an optional implicit math.Ordering argument such as Romeo Kienzler showed in a previous answer to this question. Array.sortBy(_._2) will do a reverse sort of the Array Tuple2 elements on their _2 fields just by defining an implicit reverse ordering before running the map-reduce script because it overrides the pre-existing ordering of Int. The reverse int Ordering already defined by Romeo Kienzler is:

```
// for reverse order
implicit val sortIntegersByString = new Ordering[Int] {
  override def compare(a: Int, b: Int) = a.compare(b)*(-1)
}
```

Another common way to define this reverse Ordering is to reverse the order of a and b and drop the (-1) on the right hand side of the compare definition:

```
// for reverse order
implicit val sortIntegersByString = new Ordering[Int] {
  override def compare(a: Int, b: Int) = b.compare(a)
}
```

Comment: Will this solution work for spark streaming as well. I mean will this sort words across batches.

Answer (score 20):

Doing it in more pythonic way.

```
# In descending order
''' The first parameter tells number of elements
    to be present in output.
''' 
data.takeOrdered(10, key=lambda x: -x[1])
# In Ascending order
data.takeOrdered(10, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 7):

For those looking to get top N elements ordered by value:

```
theRDD.takeOrdered(N, lambda (key, value): -1 * len(value))
```

if you wish to order by string length.

On the other hand if the values are already in the form that is suitable for your desired ordering, then:

```
theRDD.takeOrdered(N, lambda (key, value): -1 * value)
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it this way

```
// for reverse order
implicit val sortIntegersByString = new Ordering[Int] {
    override def compare(a: Int, b: Int) = a.compare(b)*(-1)
}

counts.collect.toSeq.sortBy(_._2)
```

So basically you convert your RDD to a sequence and use the sort method in order to sort it.

The block above globally changes the sort behaviour in order to get a descending sort order.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use the generic `sortBy` transformation (not an action, i.e., it returns an RDD not an array) documented [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#sortBy).

So in your case, you could do

```
wordCounts.sortBy(lambda (word, count): count)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to sort the output by values. After the reduceByKey you can swap the output like key as  value and value as key and then you can appply sortByKey method where false sorts in the Descending order. By default it will sort in the ascending order.

```
 val test=textFile.flatMap(line=> line.split(" ")).map(word=> (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @kef for python is spot on ...

The following needs to be changed -

```
.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))
```

to

```
.map(lambda a: (a[1], a[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it using Python. So I create a list of pair values and sorted it by value:

```
out = wordCounts.collect()
outSort = sorted(out, key=lambda word:word[1])
```

Comment: You are collecting all the results back to the driver and sorting there. It will work, but only if your result set is relatively small. For a solution that works at scale, see eliasah's solution.

Comment: This does not address the problem for large data. If data is small why do you need spark at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
 wordCounts.map(lambda (a,b) : (b,a)).sortByKey(ascending=False).map(lambda (a,b) : (b,a)).collect()
```

This solution works because each row of a wordCount rdd looks like this:

(WORD,COUNT)

the first map produces an rdd with the order of the tuples reversed i.e. now they look like this

(COUNT,WORD)

Now when we do sortByKey the COUNT is taken as the key which is what we want.
The second map then maps the now sorted second rdd back to the original format of

(WORD,COUNT)

for each row but not now the rows are sorted by the word count.

An implicit assumption here is that mapping does not change the order of the RDD rows otherwise the second map might mess with the sorting.

Comment: This answer would need some explanations... You can't just drop some code : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Just posting an equation isn't very helpful unless you explain what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do sortByValue using SCALA is

```
val count = oozie.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortBy(x => x._2)
```

x._2 represents the second element of any list x.

To do the sort in descending order "-x._2"

```
scala> val count = oozie.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortBy(x => -x._2)

count: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[26] at sortBy at <console>:25

scala> count.take(10)
res6: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((the,4603), (to,1707), (and,1595), (of,1337), (a,1319), (Oozie,1302), (in,1131), (.,994), (is,956), (for,753))
```

Answer (score -2):

Python way:  Now you can write a map to get value (2nd element) in key(1st) position -> sort by that key(meaning value) -> change the positions again. Simple :)

```
wordCounts.map(lambda pair: (pair[1], pair[0])).sortByKey().map(lambda pair: (pair[1], pair[0]))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it