# Fastest way to sorting a corpus dictionary into an OrderedDict - python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, counter, ordereddictionary

Given a corpus/texts as such:

```
Resumption of the session
I declare resumed the session of the European Parliament adjourned on Friday 17 December 1999 , and I would like once again to wish you a happy new year in the hope that you enjoyed a pleasant festive period .
Although , as you will have seen , the dreaded &apos; millennium bug &apos; failed to materialise , still the people in a number of countries suffered a series of natural disasters that truly were dreadful .
You have requested a debate on this subject in the course of the next few days , during this part @-@ session .
In the meantime , I should like to observe a minute &apos; s silence , as a number of Members have requested , on behalf of all the victims concerned , particularly those of the terrible storms , in the various countries of the European Union .
```

I could simply do this to get a dictionary with word frequencies:

```
>>> word_freq = Counter()
>>> for line in text.split('\n'):
...     for word in line.split():
...             word_freq[word]+=1
...
```

But if the aim is to achieve an ordered dictionary from highest to lowest frequency, I will have to do this:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> sorted_word_freq = OrderedDict()
>>> for word, freq in word_freq.most_common():
...     sorted_word_freq[word] = freq
...
```

Imagine that I have 1 billion keys in the `Counter` object, iterating through the `most_common()` would have a complexity of going through a corpus (non-unique instances) once and the vocabulary (unique key).

Note: The `Counter.most_common()` would call an ad-hoc `sorted()`, see https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e38470b49d3c/Lib/collections.py#l472

Given this, I have seen the following code that uses `numpy.argsort()`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> words = word_freq.keys()
>>> freqs = word_freq.values()
>>> sorted_word_index = np.argsort(freqs) # lowest to highest
>>> sorted_word_freq_with_numpy = OrderedDict()
>>> for idx in reversed(sorted_word_index):
...     sorted_word_freq_with_numpy[words[idx]] = freqs[idx]
...
```

**Which is faster?**

**Is there any other faster way to get such an `OrderedDict` from a `Counter`?**

**Other than `OrderedDict`, is there other python objects that achieves the same sorted key-value pair?**

Assume that memory is not an issue. Given 120 GB of RAM, there shouldn't be much issue to keep 1 billion key-value pairs right? Assume an average of 20 chars per key for 1 billion keys and a single integer for each value.

Comment: Memory may also be an issue as well as speed. I imagine some kind of merge sort would be best on both counts.  There is some discussion of the best sort in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180240/best-way-to-sort-1m-records-in-python.

Comment: assume that memory is not an issue.

Comment: Possibly a trillion key-value pair wouldn't take up that much memory right?

Comment: Well, if they're 1 byte each (which is unlikely), it would be "only" 1 TB...

Comment: Doing it on an Apache Spark cluster would be fast since it can be parallelized.  Since its key oriented keys would have to be swapped with values in order to sort by value.  Discussion on this is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656696/spark-get-collection-sorted-by-value.  See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs in the programming guide.  Here is announcement of Spark winning the Daytona Grey benchmark: https://spark.apache.org/news/spark-wins-daytona-gray-sort-100tb-benchmark.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Series` object in Pandas is an array of key-value pairs (which can have non-unique keys) which may be of interest. It has a `sort` method which sorts by the values and is implemented in Cython. Here's an example sorting an array of length one million:

```
In [39]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(1e6)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
s = pd.Series(arr, index=np.arange(1e6))
%timeit s.sort()
%timeit sorted(arr)

1 loops, best of 3: 85.8 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop
```

Given a normal Python `dict` you can construct a `Series` by calling:

```
my_series = pd.Series(my_dict)
```

Then sort by value by

```
my_series.sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

One step toward improving the speed is to fill the counter in the optimal way.

For example, with your `txt` (802 char).

```
mycounter=Counter(txt.split())
```

produces the same thing as your `word_counter`, but in 1/3 the time.

Or if you have to read the text line by line from a file, then use:

```
word_freq=Counter()
for line in txt.splitlines():
    word_freq.update(line.split())
```

Similarly the ordered dictionary can be created without the loop:

```
mydict = OrderedDict(sorted(mycounter.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Here I am calling `sorted` in the same way that `most_common` does (as per your link).  And I'm passing the list of sorted items directly to the `OrderedDict` creator.

When I look at `mycounter` in `ipython`, I get the values in sorted order:

```
In [160]: mycounter
Out[160]: Counter({'the': 13, ',': 10, 'of': 9, 'a': 7, '.': 4, 'in': 4, 'to': 3, 'have': 3, 'session': 3, '&apos;': 3, 'on': 3, 'you': 3, 'I': 3, 'that': 2, 'requested': 2, 'like': 2, 'European': 2, 'this': 2, 'countries': 2, 'as': 2, 'number': 2, 's': 1, 'various': 1, 'wish': 1, 'will': 1, 'Parliament': 1, 'meantime': 1, 'Resumption': 1, 'natural': 1, 'days': 1, 'debate': 1, 'You': 1, 'Members': 1, 'next': 1, '@-@': 1, 'hope': 1, 'enjoyed': 1, 'December': 1, 'victims': 1, 'particularly': 1, 'millennium': 1, .... 'behalf': 1, 'were': 1, 'failed': 1})
```

That's because its `__repr__` method calls `most_common`. Again this is from your link.

```
items = ', '.join(map('%r: %r'.__mod__, self.most_common()))
```

On further testing I see that calling `sorted` directly doesn't save time:

```
In [166]: timeit mycounter.most_common()
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.1 µs per loop

In [167]: timeit sorted(mycounter.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.5 µs per loop

In [168]: timeit OrderedDict(mycounter.most_common())
1000 loops, best of 3: 225 µs per loop
```

In this case, loading the dictionary directly doesn't save time either.  Your iteration does just as well:

```
In [174]: %%timeit 
   .....: sorteddict=OrderedDict()
   .....: for word,freq in word_freq.most_common():
    sorteddict[word]=freq
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 224 µs per loop
```

For this sample, using `np.argsort` does not help (timewise).  Just calling `argsort` is slower than `most_common`.

```
In [178]: timeit np.argsort(list(mycounter.values()))
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.2 µs per loop
```

Most of that time is in converting the list to an array, `x=np.array(list(mycounter.values()))`.  `np.argsort(x)` is much faster.  That's true of a lot of `numpy` functionality.  When operating on arrays `numpy` is fast.  But there's a lot of overhead when converting lists to arrays.

I can create the OrderedDict via `numpy` in one line with:

```
OrderedDict(np.sort(np.array(list(mycounter.items()), dtype='a12,i'), order='f1')[::-1])
```

or in pieces:

```
lla = np.array(list(mycounter.items()),dtype='a12,i')
lla.sort(order='f1')
OrderedDict(lla[::-1])
```

I'm making a structured array from the `items()`, sorting that by the 2nd field, and then making the dictionary.  No time savings though.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837513/901925 for another recent example of using `order` to sort a structured array.