# How to sort by value efficiently in PySpark?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, apache-spark

I want to sort my K,V tuples by V, i.e. by the value.  I know that `TakeOrdered` is good for this if you know how many you need:

```
b = sc.parallelize([('t',3),('b',4),('c',1)])
```

Using `TakeOrdered:`

```
b.takeOrdered(3,lambda atuple: atuple[1])
```

Using `Lambda`

```
b.map(lambda aTuple: (aTuple[1], aTuple[0])).sortByKey().map(
    lambda aTuple: (aTuple[0], aTuple[1])).collect()
```

I've checked out the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656696/spark-get-collection-sorted-by-value), which suggests the latter.  I find it hard to believe that `takeOrdered` is so succinct and yet it requires the same number of operations as the `Lambda` solution.

Does anyone know of a simpler, more concise Transformation in spark to sort by value?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think `sortBy()` is more concise:

```
b = sc.parallelize([('t', 3),('b', 4),('c', 1)])
bSorted = b.sortBy(lambda a: a[1])
bSorted.collect()
...
[('c', 1),('t', 3),('b', 4)]
```

It's actually [not more efficient at all](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd-pysrc.html#RDD.sortBy) as it involves keying by the values, sorting by the keys, and then grabbing the values but it looks prettier than your latter solution. In terms of efficiency, I don't think you'll find a more efficient solution as you would need a way to transform your data such that values will be your keys (and then eventually transform that data back to the original schema).

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add this tip.. which helped me out alot

Ascending:

```
bSorted = b.sortBy(lambda a: a[1])
```

Descending:

```
bSorted = b.sortBy(lambda a: -a[1])
```